# Backbone fetch response failure on IE8

Tags: json, google-app-engine, backbone.js, fetch

I have a backbone project that is calling a service on Google App Engine that returns JSON data. backbone collection "parse" is not being called nor am I getting an error in backbone... This issue seems to be limited to IE8 because IE7 and IE9 actually work. Chrome, Firefox, etc... all work as well.

Comment: You need to provide more information than that if you want people to be able to help you. Sample code would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with cross domain in IE8. I fixed it by adding XDomainRequest to my initialize in my Backbone Collection.

```
initialize: function(){
            $this = this;

            //fix for IE8 and IE9
            if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 9 && window.XDomainRequest) {
                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();

                xdr.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/service");
                xdr.onload = function(){
                    $this.parse($.parseJSON(xdr.responseText));
                };
                xdr.send();
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

For any future users, I suggest checking out this drop-in script to extend Backbone's ajax functionality and add support for older IE browsers automatically. Does something similar to the OP's answer in that it adds xDomainRequests, but less work for you. :-)

https://github.com/victorquinn/Backbone.CrossDomain